# Kotlin Serialize object to YAML where YAML node should be a value

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-yaml

Jackson contains [YAML Dataformat](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text) module, which helps to work with this format. The example and tests in the repository are quite straighforward. However, I have a case that I struggle to implement at the moment.

Let's say I have a structure:

```
    data class Department(val name: String, val employees: List<Employee>)
    data class Employee(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int)
```

I would like it to become a YAML with a structure:

```
departments:
   I.T:
      name: I.T
      employees:
         Steve Jobs:
            firstName: Steve
            lastName: Jobs
            age: 24
```

Essentially, I would like the node name in YAML to be constructed from the value of the object. Is it possible at all?